# OnRowUpdating Does not take value of edit template textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, webforms

I am trying to update a value in my gridview on row updating. However, it refuses to take in the value written in the textbox. I populate the gridview if the page is not post back. Help!

GRIDVIEW:

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode=Conditional><ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="searchGV" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"
        CssClass="mGrid" EmptyDataText="The Search Did Not Return Any Results"
        PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" Width="100%" OnRowCancelingEdit="searchGV_RowCancelingEdit"
        OnRowEditing="searchGV_RowEditing" DataKeyNames="media_id" OnRowUpdating="searchGV_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="media_id" Visible="false" HeaderText="" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="dir_path" Visible="false" HeaderText="Dir" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Taken" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="dateLinkCsBtn" OnClientClick='<%#Eval("dir_path","Javascript:return test(\"{0}\",event);")%>'
                        runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("date") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Media Type">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="mediaTypeLbl" Text='<%#Eval("description") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Alias File Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="aliasFileName" Text='<%#Bind("alias_file_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("alias_file_name") %>' ID="updateAliasTxt"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FillGrid();
    }

}

protected void searchGV_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    searchGV.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    FillGrid();
}
protected void searchGV_RowCancelingEdit(object sender,
                          GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    searchGV.EditIndex = -1;
    FillGrid();
}

public void FillGrid()
{
    Media_DAO media_query = new Media_DAO();
    searchGV.DataSource = media_query.get_search_media(alias_file_name_txt.Text.Trim(), Convert.ToInt16(mediaTypeDDL.SelectedValue),
            from_date_txt.Text.Trim(), to_date_txt.Text.Trim(), Convert.ToInt16(Session["user_id"]));
    searchGV.DataBind();
}

protected void searchGV_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    GridViewRow row = searchGV.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    TextBox new_alias = (TextBox)searchGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("updateAliasTxt");
    int media_id = Convert.ToInt16(searchGV.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["media_id"]);

    Media_DAO media_query2 = new Media_DAO();
    media_query2.update_alias_name_by_id(media_id, new_alias.Text.Trim(), Convert.ToInt16(Session["user_id"]));
    searchGV.EditIndex = -1;
    FillGrid();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

while declaring the grid you have specified only **1** **data key value**

```
asDataKeyNames="media_id"
```

DateKeys for grid view is stored in array format starting from 0.
The error may be in getting the **media_id** while updating. You need to change it as follows.

```
protected void searchGV_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    GridViewRow row = searchGV.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    TextBox new_alias = (TextBox)searchGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("updateAliasTxt");
    int media_id = Convert.ToInt16(e.Keys[0]); //this will get the media_id

    Media_DAO media_query2 = new Media_DAO();
    media_query2.update_alias_name_by_id(media_id, new_alias.Text.Trim(), Convert.ToInt16(Session["user_id"]));
    searchGV.EditIndex = -1;
    FillGrid();
}
```

Since the earlier method was `searchGV.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["media_id"]` , you might not get the media_id value if the row number which you are trying to edit is greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

The [**`DataKeys`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of GridView returns a collection of [**`DataKey`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datakey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects that represents the data key value of each row for a GridView. Thus, `DataKeys[1]` gives 2nd row, `DataKeys[4]` gives 5th row ...

Therefore, you need to use either the [**`Value`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datakey.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) OR the [**`Values`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datakey.values%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to access the value of a key field.

Rather than doing this:

```
int media_id = Convert.ToInt16(searchGV.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["media_id"]);
```

do this:

```
int media_id = Convert.ToInt16(searchGV.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["media_id"]);
// You can also use the Value property which gives the key value at index 0 
int media_id = Convert.ToInt16(searchGV.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
```